# Nesting an undefined number of loops in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have an array in java, of changing length (around 3-5). Now I want to change the value of each element to each possible element of another array (newvalues) so that all combinations

I'd normally just do a loop in a loop, but in this case the number of loops is defined by the length of the array. So I'm strangely confused. Take this example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> originalList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); \\has varying length
ArrayList<Integer> newvalues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

originalList.add(0);
originalList.add(0);

newvalues.add(1);
newvalues.add(2);
newvalues.add(3);
```

The array now is:

```
0 0
```

I want to loop trough all of these to perform an action with them:

```
1 1
1 2 
1 3
2 1 
2 2
2 3
...
```

I know this will become exponentially large, but since the original array should not be very big it should be ok.

Comment: This seems like a problem that can be solved with **recursion**.

Comment: But if you're switching the values of the first array to be all permutations of the values in the 2nd array, why does the created array have 3 elements instead of two?

Comment: Jim W, you are right, my bad. I've updated the question. Clashsoft: ah, recusion, that's interesting. I kind of forgot about that, I feel like it might be bad practice to do this thing.

Comment: Next question, if you put 0, 1 in the first array, would 0 only appear in the first position of the created array or in both of them? If you want to put 0, 1 , 2, 3 in your array and you want it to be of length two, why don't you just omit the original array and specify the length and the allowed values for the elements?

Comment: Hi Jim W. I got confused because in my real code the current values are included in the new values. To simplify it I just removed the zeros here.

Comment: Any suggestions on what type of recursion would be good to use?

Comment: Why are their two numbers per row? The arraylist you created is a single dimensional array.

Comment: Well each row represents the full array. So there are values I want to loop through

Comment: I made it an arraylist of arraylists of integers. There are risks, as pointed out in my answer below. I would bet that the problem you're trying to solve is amenable to a less horrible solution, but I don't know the greater goal you're attempting to accomplish with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
static void loop(List<Integer> originalList, List<Integer> newvalues, int index) {
    if (index >= originalList.size())
        System.out.println(originalList);
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < newvalues.size(); ++i) {
            originalList.set(index, newvalues.get(i));
            loop(originalList, newvalues, index + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
    ArrayList<Integer> originalList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> newvalues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    originalList.add(0);
    originalList.add(0);

    newvalues.add(1);
    newvalues.add(2);
    newvalues.add(3);

    loop(originalList, newvalues, 0);
```

result:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for this. And to be safe, I have actually limited the list size to two.  This type of programming makes me nervous :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you really need an array of all the values permutated through? Questions that result in answers consisting of huge arrays and recursion are almost always a sign that you're thinking about the problem wrong.

Anyway, here is what you requested. When I look at this, I sort of cringe because of how dangerous this code is. If you use this with anything more than tiny sizes of length, you will rapidly run out of both heap and stack space.

```
main()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> allowedValues = new ArrayList<>();
    allowedValues.add(0);
    allowedValues.add(1);
    allowedValues.add(2);
    allowedValues.add(3);
    int length = 2;

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> billionsAndBillions = new ArrayList<>();

    appendPermutations (allowedValues, billionsAndBillions, 2);
}

private List appendPermutation(List<Integer> values, List<List<Integer>> pile, int depth)
{
    depth --;
    if (pile.isEmpty())
    {       
        for (Integer value: values)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
            tmp.add(value);
            pile.add(tmp);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (List<Integer> list: pile)
    {       
        ArrayList<Integer> permutation = list.copy();
        for (Integer value: values)
        {
            permutation.add(value);
            newList.add(permutation);
        }
    }
    if (depth > 0)
    {
        newList = appendPermutation(values, newList, depth);
    }
    return newList;
}
```